# How do I ignore a URL rewrite when there are no arguments?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want my users to specify friendly URLS for some of the content they will be adding through my CMS. However, .htaccess is not really my strong suit (I generally avoid it like the plague).

Here is what I have so far that is *almost* working perfectly:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^arg/([0-9a-z\-]+)/?$    index.php?arg=$1    [NC,L]
```

Obviously - I probably won't be using "`/arg`" to specify this in production, but for all intents and purposes, it works for right now.

This probably goes without saying - but all requests that would normally look like:
`index.php?arg=some-argument` not look like `/arg/some-argument` which is exactly what I want.

**Here's the problem**

Now - If a user ends up at `index.php` without passing an argument - it 404s. I would like to present the end user with a list of page-specific options - rather than sending them to a generic 404. How do I go about this?

**Edit:**
I answered the question because I found something that *works* - however, I don't fully understand everything going on in my answer, if someone can break down exactly what is happening - or even just validate that I am doing this the *right* way - I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

After quite a bit of searching - I found my answer, and yes - it was as easy as I assumed it would be (when you dig/Google hard enough).

I needed to use `RewriteCond` to check for a query string. I still don't fully understand everything happening here, but this did deliver the desired result.

**Code**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET /.*;.* HTTP/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteRule    ^arg/([0-9a-z\-]+)/?$    index.php?arg=$1    [NC,L]    # Handle product requests
```